# Using AWS CLI to enable encryption for SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

is there a way to use the AWS CLI to modify attributes of an SNS topic ?
I'm trying to enable Encryption for an SNS topic but the documentation presented here

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-enable-encryption-for-topic.html

only specifies 2 methods:

1. Using the AWS Console
2. Using the Java AWS SDK

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you are looking for:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/set-topic-attributes.html

```
--attribute-name (string)

A map of attributes with their corresponding values.

The following attribute applies only to server-side-encryption :

KmsMasterKeyId - The ID of an AWS-managed customer master key (CMK) for Amazon SNS or a custom CMK. For more information, see Key Terms . For more examples, see KeyId in the AWS Key Management Service API Reference .
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [set-topic-attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/set-topic-attributes.html) command.

Example:

```
aws sns set-topic-attributes --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic --attribute-name KmsMasterKeyId --attribute-value arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:111122223333:alias/ExampleAlias
```

You can also use the key id, key id arn or just alias name for the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt it by using the default KMS key.

```
aws sns set-topic-attributes --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:<account>:<snstopic> --attribute-name KmsMasterKeyId --attribute-value "alias/aws/sns"
```